# Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I already tried different versions of babel and webpack but this issue still the same. It's not error in my webpack.config.js?
As you can see, the version of webpack there is low, maybe it's on the version of webpack if these are the errors?

I tried lower version of babel and still the same, I really can't figure this out. Already 24 hours problem and I stil can't fix this problem. I want to upgrade in ReactJS version 16.

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require("path")
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

// new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {

module.exports = {

  context: __dirname,
  entry: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './app/modules/common/index'
  ],

  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./app/static/bundles/'),
      filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
      publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/app/static/bundles/',
       // Tell django to use this URL to load packages and not use STATIC_URL + bundle_name
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(), // don't reload if there is an error
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
    { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: "file-loader?name=public/icons/[name].[ext]"},
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015','react']
        }
    },
    ],
  },

  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
}
```

Babel Configuration (.babelrc, package.json, cli command)

**package.json**

```
{
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.0.1",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
"react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
"webpack": "^1.9.8",
"webpack-bundle-tracker": "0.0.5",
"webpack-cli": "^2.1.3",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.9.0",
"mobx-logger": "^0.5.0",
"mobx-react-devtools": "^4.2.11",
"file-loader": "^0.11.2"
"react": "^16.6.3",
"react-dom": "^16.6.3",
  },
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

**ERROR SCREENSHOT:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it now, I changed my **webpack.config.js**

```
query: { presets: [ '@babel/env', '@babel/react', ]
```